# Spherical coordinates triple integral, help

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, multiple-integral, jacobian, change-of-variable

I have the following triple integral with the instructions

By using spherical coordinates, evaluate the integral:
$$L = \iiint_{D} \frac{1}{\sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)} dxdydz$$

Where D is the portion of the unit cylinder $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$ which lies between $z =0 $ and $z = 1$

My thoughts were that we use the bounds and use the Jacobian:

$$0 \leq \rho \leq \sqrt2, $$
$$0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi  $$
$$0 \leq \varphi \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$$

To which after computing, we end up with the result
$$\pi(\sqrt2 - 2)$$

I was hoping someone could either correct me, or verify. And if you do verify it, is there a method which is easier or different, because I would want to learn it thank you!

Comment: In fact, my first thought would be to use *cylindrical* co-ordinates, as they are better suited to the shape $D$. ($x=\rho\cos\theta, y=\rho\sin\theta, z=z$ with $0\le\rho\le 1, 0\le\theta\le 2\pi, 0\le z\le 1$.) With *spherical* co-ordinates you are better off setting $0\le\theta\le 2\pi, 0\le \varphi\le \pi/4$ (as you did!), but $0\le\rho\cos\varphi\le 1$ i.e. $0\le \rho\le\frac{1}{\cos\varphi}$ (*rather than* $0\le\rho\le\sqrt{2}$)...

Comment: Cylindrical would definitely be better suited here (it's a cylinder for crying out loud) but I think the instructions required him to use spherical.

Comment: @StephenDonovan I know ... but at the end the OP said "is there a method which is easier or different" so I thought I'd state the obvious...

Comment: Fair enough, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The region you are integrating over is cylinder $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1, 0 \leq z \leq 1$

So it is easier to find the limits of integration in cylindrical coordinates.

$x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta, z$

Your integrand becomes $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2 + z^2}}$

And your integral is $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{r} {\sqrt{r^2+z^2}} \, dr \, dz \, d\theta$

EDIT: In spherical coordinates,

Your integral is $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/4} \int_0^{1 / \cos \phi} \rho \sin \phi\, d \rho \, d\phi \, d\theta + \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{1 / \sin \phi} \rho \sin \phi\, d \rho \, d\phi \, d\theta$

Here is a diagram that shows why $\rho$ is $\frac{1}{\cos \phi}$ (as $z \leq 1$) for $0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Also why $\rho$ is $\frac{1}{\cos (\frac{\pi}{2} - \phi)} = \frac{1}{\sin \phi}$ (as radius of cylinder is $1$) for $\frac{\pi}{4} \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

[image]

Comment: That makes a lot of sense thank you!

Comment: But there is one mistake I spotted. Let me correct that.

Comment: I don't think the statement in your Edit is correct.  You still need two pieces.

Comment: @B.Goddard I already wrote I spotted a mistake and I was correcting.

Answer (score 2):

That answer that you got is negative, and therefore it cannot possibly be correct.

You can do it in cylindrical coordinates:\begin{align}\iiint_D\frac{\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac\rho{\sqrt{\rho^2+z^2}}\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=2\pi\int_0^1\sqrt{1+z^2}-z\,\mathrm dz\\&=\pi\left(\sqrt2-1+\operatorname{arcsinh}(1)\right).\end{align}

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your bounds aren't right.  To use spherical coordinates, you'll have to breach the region into two pieces.  One piece has bounds:

$$0\leq \rho \leq \sec\phi,\; 0\leq \phi \leq \pi/4,\; 0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi.$$

The other has:

$$0\leq \rho \leq \csc\phi,\; \pi/4\leq \phi \leq \pi/2,\; 0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi.$$

The equations $\rho = \sec\phi$ and $\rho = \csc\phi$ are the equations of horizontal and vertical lines in the $\rho\phi$-plane.